# Jaws not allowing enter value in textbox after press enter key in IE11

Tags: accessibility, internet-explorer-11

When Jaws is on , it's reading the entered value in textbox, once click on Enter button on keyboard, it's not allowing to enter value in it. We have to manually focus out from textbox, how a physically disabled person identify , he has to focus out of the textbox. This is working fine in all browsers , but in IE 11 only it's not working.

Here is my code currently

```
<label for="email" id="email_label" class="FieldContainer---label---1bv0f">Email</label>

<input id="email" name="email" type="text" min="0" aria-required="true" autocomplete="off"  placeholder="" aria-describedby="email" value="">
```

Comment: Not quite sure what you're asking for.  Are you saying after you type in the input and press enter, that you can't type anything else in the input?  And this only happens when jaws is running?  Is jaws changing from forms mode to virtual pc cursor mode?  (you'd hear an audible sound when it does that).  If you switch out of forms mode, then typing a letter would actually run the jaws shortcut key.  For example, typing 'H' would try to navigate to the next heading instead of typing an 'H' in the input.

Comment: Yes, it's happening only Jaws running, I am unable to enter value sin text box. Thanks

Comment: I'm noticing some **invalid attributes**, that you might want to clean up and try again. `min` is only valid for `type="number"`, `aria-describedby="email"` is referencing the element itself, you should drop it entirely, since you do have a label.

Comment: Related: `type="email"` would help many users, and `autocomplete="off"` is reducing usability to many, if they are not supposed to enter other peoples' data. Is there a reason to use `aria-required` instead of `required`?